# How to set Qmake -project default values?

Tags: qt, qmake

Was wondering if its possible to set QMake to have default Pro file creation values such that when I enter 'qmake -project' it will add 'QT+=widgets' everytime??

Thanks

Comment: Did you have a look in the [manual](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-manual.html)?

Comment: If you choose the correct type of project QMake will add what is necessary.

Comment: Trust me I have been reading the manual but could not find a solution. Best I could find is that all the configuration settings are in the 'MKSPECS' folder and I have not been able to find what ever template qmake uses to setup the .PRO file so I can put in my own defaults.  Thanks.

Comment: I found a solution. I recompiled Qmake to include that prefix automatically.